# Typescript TS2349 when trying to use a function in a React render prop with Apollo Query and Formik

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-apollo, formik

I'm new to TypeScript and have now been stuck on this for two nights. I'm trying to use `Formik` for Apollo's Query with a render prop and I'm getting a `TS2349` error stating that:

Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'QueryResult' has no compatible call signatures on the following lines...

```
const response = await listItems({
                    variables: {
                      filter: {
                        sku: {
                          eq: sku
                        }
                      }
                    },
                  });
```

Full code is as follows :

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Formik } from "formik";
import { Form, Input, Label, Button } from "reactstrap";
import { Query, Mutation } from "react-apollo";
import gql from "graphql-tag";
import "react-table/react-table.css";

import {
  ListItemsQuery,
  ListItemsQueryVariables
} from "./API";
import { listItems } from "./graphql/queries";

interface FormValues {
  sku: string;
}

export const CheckSkuForm = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Query<ListItemsQuery, ListItemsQueryVariables>
        query={gql(listItems)}
        variables={{
          filter: {
            sku: {
              eq: "test"
            },
            inventory: {
              eq: true
            },
            scannedMissing: {
              eq: false
            },
            scannedFound: {
              eq: false
            }

          }
        }}
      >
        {listItems => (
          <Formik<FormValues>
            initialValues={{
              sku: "",
            }}
            onSubmit={async ({ sku }, { resetForm }) => {
              // call mutation

              const response = await listItems({
                variables: {
                  filter: {
                    sku: {
                      eq: sku
                    }
                  }
                },
              });
              console.log(response);
              resetForm();
            }}
          >
            {({ values, handleChange, handleSubmit }) => (
              <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <Label>sku</Label>
                <Input
                  name="sku"
                  value={values.sku}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  margin="normal"
                />
                <br />
                <Button type="submit">
                  Submit
                      </Button>
              </Form>
            )}
          </Formik>
        )}
      </Query>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: It seems there's a misunderstanding of how to use the Query component. The query result (`listItems` in this case) has a `data` property on it, which is the data returned from the query. It's not a function. What are you trying to accomplish here? I'm guessing, update the query's variables on submit? Maybe you wanted to use the Mutation component instead?

Comment: That is exactly what I'm trying to accomplish. Return a list of the values based on the form submission for the input of sku.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @kingdaro I was able to figure this out.

Turns out the Query component doesn't have an attached function to trigger it manually. You are better off using the example from the Apollo team here. 
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/queries.html#manual-query

Here is my code rewritten using both Apollo and Formik.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Formik } from "formik";
import { Form, Input, Label, Button } from "reactstrap";
import { ApolloConsumer } from 'react-apollo';
import gql from "graphql-tag";
import { listItems } from "./graphql/queries";

interface FormValues {
  sku: string;
}

export const CheckSkuForm = () => {

  return (
    <ApolloConsumer>
      {client => (
        <div>
          <Formik<FormValues>
            initialValues={{
              sku: "",
            }}
            onSubmit={async ({ sku }, { resetForm }) => {
              const { data }: any = await client.query({
                query: gql(listItems),
                variables: { filter: { sku: { eq: sku } } }
              });
              console.log({ data });
              resetForm();
            }}
          >
            {({ values, handleChange, handleSubmit }) => (
              <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <Label>sku</Label>
                <Input
                  name="sku"
                  value={values.sku}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  margin="normal"
                />
                <br />
                <Button type="submit">
                  Submit
                      </Button>
              </Form>
            )}
          </Formik>
        </div>
      )}
    </ApolloConsumer>
  );
};
```